# How can i link my jButtons to methods in other class in the same package

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Actually I'm working on a game in java and I want to start new game when user would click on the jButton (New Game) that I've created in a class 'Window' under the same package which contains all my game components. Now I want to access the method 'newGame()' defined in class Framework in my buttonActionPerformed() method but without calling the constructor of framework.

```
       private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {                                         
   Framework f = new Framework();
    f.newGame();         
}
```

I'm using this code but it is showing many errors because I have used

```
          this.setContentPane(new Framework());
```

in the constructor of Window class .This is a part of my framework class

```
public class Framework extends Canvas {
public Framework ()
{
    super();

    gameState = GameState.VISUALIZING;

    //We start game in new thread.
    Thread gameThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            GameLoop();
        }
    };
    gameThread.start();
    }
     private void GameLoop()
     {
           long visualizingTime = 0, lastVisualizingTime = System.nanoTime();

    // This variables are used for calculating the time that defines for how long we should put threat to sleep to meet the GAME_FPS.
    long beginTime, timeTaken, timeLeft;

    while(true)
    {
        beginTime = System.nanoTime();

        switch (gameState)
        {
            case PLAYING:
                gameTime += System.nanoTime() - lastTime;

                game.UpdateGame(gameTime, mousePosition());

                lastTime = System.nanoTime();
            break;
            case GAMEOVER:
                //...
            break;
            case MAIN_MENU:
                //...
            break;
            case OPTIONS:
                //...
            break;
            case GAME_CONTENT_LOADING:
                //...
            break;
            case STARTING:
                // Sets variables and objects.
                Initialize();
                // Load files - images, sounds, ...
                LoadContent();

                // When all things that are called above finished, we change game status to main menu.
                gameState = GameState.MAIN_MENU;
            break;
            case VISUALIZING:
                        if(this.getWidth() > 1 && visualizingTime > secInNanosec)
                {
                    frameWidth = this.getWidth();
                    frameHeight = this.getHeight();

                    // When we get size of frame we change status.
                    gameState = GameState.STARTING;
                }
                else
                {
                    visualizingTime += System.nanoTime() - lastVisualizingTime;
                    lastVisualizingTime = System.nanoTime();
                }
            break;
        }

        // Repaint the screen.
        repaint();               // goes to paint component in canvas

        timeTaken = System.nanoTime() - beginTime;
        timeLeft = (GAME_UPDATE_PERIOD - timeTaken) / milisecInNanosec; 
        if (timeLeft < 10) 
            timeLeft = 10; //set a minimum
        try {
             Thread.sleep(timeLeft);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
    }
      }
     public void newGame()
      {
      // We set gameTime to zero and lastTime to current time for later calculations.
       if(true)
        {
          BufferedImage blankCursorImg = 
                       new BufferedImage(16, 16,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Cursor blankCursor =       
               Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(blankCursorImg, new Point(0, 0), null);
        this.setCursor(blankCursor);
    }
    gameTime = 0;
    lastTime = System.nanoTime();

    game = new Game();
  } 
}
```

And here is WindowForm.java which contains the main() and the jButtons
     package helicopterbattle;

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

  public class WindowForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  public WindowForm() {
     this.setTitle("Helicopter battle");
     if(true) // Full screen mode
    {  
        this.setUndecorated(true);
         this.setExtendedState(this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
     this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // Creates the instance of the Framework.java that extends the Canvas.java and puts it on the frame.
    this.setContentPane(new Framework());
     initComponents();
     jButton1.setBounds(630,490,100,30);
     jButton2.setBounds(630,540,100,30);
      } 
     private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.exit(0);
}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    Framework f = new Framework();
    f.newGame();
      jButton1.setVisible(false);
    jButton2.setVisible(false);
}                          
  public static void main(String args[]) {
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new WindowForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
  public javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
  public javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
  // End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

Please help and thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the errors you are getting?

Comment: That's a massive design issue that would be impossible to answer without having more context. You should start by having a "model" and "controller" which represents the virtual state of the game and what can be done against that model. You would ensure that each section of your game had access to the controller (normally by passing it as a reference). The controller would then be used to modify the state of the model, wch would then provide notification to the view so the view could update itself...

Comment: @TNT Here are the errors I'm getting -  Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at helicopterbattle.Framework.GameLoop(Framework.java:148)
 at helicopterbattle.Framework.access$000(Framework.java:18)
 at helicopterbattle.Framework$1.run(Framework.java:84)

Comment: It looks like your error is in GameLoop, which is left off from your sample code that you put into the question. If we could see that method we may be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: GameLoop() is working properly coz when i call newGame() method from within the Framework class it is accessible. My problem is how to call newGame() method through jButton1 in WindowForm class ?

Comment: @ Eric Hydrick -I've added the content of GameLoop() ,hope this would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to call `newGame()` method without creating a new object from `Framework` class

I think you can achieve this by declare a final variable in `WindowForm` class before the constructor as follow

```
private final Framework myFramework = new Framework();
```

then pass it to `setContentPane` method

```
setContentPane(myFramework);
```

and use the same object inside `jButton1ActionPerformed` method

```
myFramework.newGame();
```

--

An alternative solution is using Singleton design pattern to create a static instance from `Framework` class and call `Framework.getInstance()` whenever you want